# How to give image for the action link with confirmation dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below code doesn't work.

It works correctly without `confirm`, but with `confirm` it doesn't work.

```
<a href="@Url.Action ("action" , "controller" , new {idd=item.id } , new { onclick="return confirm ( ' are you sure ?');"})">
 <Img src=@Url.Content ("~/Content/icons/tag.icon")" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Url.Action does not have the htmlAttributes parameter like some Html Helpers, etc. Just add the onclick="..." directly to the 'a' tag.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Test2", "Home", new { idd = 2 })" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?');">
```